# How to make a Dynamic Resource ESRI Button as small as needed in an ArcGIS Pro Window?

Tags: arcgis-pro, c#, wpf, arcgis-api-wpf

How to make a button, on a ProWindow in an ArcGIS Pro Add-in, as large or small as I need?

To create an Add-In for ArcGIS Pro, that adjusts for both dark mode and light mode, one needs to use the xaml class:ProWindow. The button option for a Pro Window, which adjusts to either dark mode or light mode, is:

Style="{DynamicResource Esri_Button}"

My problem is: this style of button doesn't adjust to a small width. How do I override the auto-size of the dynamic resource button (or some other button I might not know about, a button option that functions for dark mode & light mode), and then make it as small as I wish?

I am using Visual Studio 2022.

Here is an example, an Add-in button. I would like the "OK" button to be a small square, Width="20", just barely containing the text, "OK."

xaml:

```
     <controls:ProWindow x:Class="Test_DarkModeProWindow.DarkLightProWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ArcGIS.Desktop.Framework.Controls;assembly=ArcGIS.Desktop.Framework"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:extensions="clr-namespace:ArcGIS.Desktop.Extensions;assembly=ArcGIS.Desktop.Extensions"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="DarkLightProWindow" Height="300" Width="300"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"
    >
    <controls:ProWindow.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <extensions:DesignOnlyResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ArcGIS.Desktop.Framework;component\Themes\Default.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </controls:ProWindow.Resources>
    <Grid>

        <StackPanel Margin="10">
            <TextBlock Text="Enter your message:" FontSize="16" />
            <TextBox x:Name="inputTextBox" Width="200" FontSize="14" />
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Button x:Name="closeButton" Content="Close" Width="80" Click="CloseButton_Click"
                        Style="{DynamicResource Esri_Button}" Margin="0 0 5 0" />
                <Button x:Name="okButton" Content="OK" Width="20" Click="OkButton_Click"
                        Style="{DynamicResource Esri_Button}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</controls:ProWindow>
```

notice that the button is the size I wish in Visual Studio 2022, but does not appear so in ArcGIS Pro.

Simple button code:

```
namespace Test_DarkModeProWindow
{
    internal class Button1 : Button
    {
        private static DarkLightProWindow _darkLightProWindow;

        protected override void OnClick()
        {
            // a simple text entry window, for demonstration
            ShowDarkLightWindow();
        }

        private void ShowDarkLightWindow()
        {
            if (_darkLightProWindow != null) { return; }

            _darkLightProWindow = new () { Owner = FrameworkApplication.Current.MainWindow };
            _darkLightProWindow.Closed += (o, e) => { _darkLightProWindow = null; };
            _darkLightProWindow.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

xaml.cs:

```
namespace Test_DarkModeProWindow
{
// The goal is to make any button as small or large as I wish
// While the button still functions in a Pro Window
// And the button auto-adjusts to dark mode or light mode
// The "OK" button is the example

    public partial class DarkLightProWindow : ArcGIS.Desktop.Framework.Controls.ProWindow
    {
        public DarkLightProWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void CloseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            
            Close();
        }

        private void OkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string userMessage = inputTextBox.Text.Trim();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userMessage))
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(userMessage);
                
                Hide();
            }
            else
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Please enter a message.");
            }
        }

    }
}
```